# Java: How do I create an array that will store an Image name and it's X, Y coordinates

Tags: java, arrays, object, coordinates, mouse

I need to create a sticker project for my computer science class. Basically, we have a palette of stickers that we must place on the canvas. The second iteration of our project requires us to code the program such that it will store the name and X, Y coordinates of our image when the image is placed on the canvas. Here is my code so far:

#### Sticker class

```
public class Stickers 
{

    public static int x, y; //create in x and y
    public EZImage name; //image name

    public Stickers(EZImage name, int Xmouse, int Ymouse) //create member function called Stickers and hold the image name and its x and y positions
    {
        x = Xmouse; //*****Variable I am trying to get*****
        y = Ymouse; //*****Variable I am trying to get*****

    }


}
```

#### Main Project

```
int Xmouse; //x coordinate
int Ymouse; //y coordinate
int whatPic = 0; //what pic was last clicked
int placedPic = 0; //what pick was placed
int slot = -1; //correspond to array slot, starting with 0

Stickers[] placedStickers = new Stickers[20];

placedStickers[slot] = new Stickers("Pacman.png", Xmouse, Ymouse); 

    if (whatPic == 3)
    { 
        if (EZInteraction.wasMouseLeftButtonReleased())
        {                                    
           if (laptopBack.isPointInElement(Xmouse, Ymouse))
           {          
            EZ.addImage("heisenberg.png", Xmouse, Ymouse); 
            placedPic = 3; 
            slot ++; //increment slot by 1
            placedStickers[slot] = new Stickers("Pacman.png", Xmouse, Ymouse); 
           }
        }
    }
```

#### Problem

So I created a while loop that constantly checks what the X, Y coordinate of the mouse is when I place a sticker (that is why the sticker knows where to be placed when clicked on the canvas). I did not include the code for this. My question is, how do I tell the array I want to store the X, Y coordinate of the mouse when I place a sticker on the canvas. i.e, I click on picture1. Name of picture1 gets stored into array. Array stores the X, Y coordinate of my mouse when I placed/clicked sticker1 onto the canvas.

Any help would be appreciated, I need to get this project done by today.

Comment: What you need is a mouse event handler. Create an instance of the MouseListener class (if you're not using any conflicting API, i dunno about that) and define its mouseClicked-or-something method to store its X,Y variables on your Sticker object

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. I am a first year CS major with no prior experience. Please explain at an idiots level what you are talking about.

Comment: Nevermind, i thought you were having trouble using a MouseListener, but that doesn't seem to be the case, since you're using EZInteration that implements it. If you don't know how to obtain the x and y coordinates of your mouse, use the static methods `EZInteraction.getXMouse()` and `EZInteraction.getYMouse()`

Comment: Thats what I used in the first iteration of the project. In the second Iteration, I am having trouble storing that particular X, Y coordinate in the array when the sticker is placed. My professor told me I had to use classes? I'm not quite sure.

Comment: since the x and y attributes on the Sticker Class are public, you can modify them with `nameofasticker.x = xMouse;`. If you have your array already filled with instances of the sticker class, then use `placedStickers[pos].x = xMouse;` or something like that

Comment: I should point out that directly modifying attributes from outside is a bit frowned upon. It may be a better idea to declare those attributes as privates and create getters and setters methods for them

Comment: I'm a bit confused, how would that look in my code?